# Regexp, wrap each CSV field in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

Using a regular expression, I can't find a solution to wrap each field from a csv text into double quotes.
The issue is that there could be already double-quoted fields.

Example:

```
Country;Product Family;Product SKU;Commercial Status
Germany;Aprobil;"Apro&amp;&#39;bil_1_5 mL";Actively Marketed
```

Should be

```
"Country";"Product Family";"Product SKU";"Commercial Status"
"Germany";"Aprobil";"Apro&amp;&#39;bil_1_5 mL";"Actively Marketed"
```

Basically, I have a problem to get two logical part in a regular expression...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The problem is you use semi colon to separate tokens, but semi colon is also in the text as html entities.

Comment: yes, so that means, I need to combine two expressions in one:
first: get all tokens without quotes and ignore those which are already in qoutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to to do 2 replacements, I think, first regex looks like this:

```
/([\w ]+[^;\n]*|\"[^\"]*\")/g
```

The regex will either match:

1. Any `Word` character or `Space`, 1 or more times, followed by any char not being semi colon '`;`' or `newline`, any number of times.
2. A double `quote` followed by any characters not being double quote, any number of times, ending with a double quote.

You then replace the matches with: `\"\1\"`.

Fianally you replace 2 double quotes with a single one.

In JavaScript this is:

```
var test = 'Country;Product Family;Product SKU;Commercial Status\n'
    + 'Germany;Aprobil;"Apro&amp;&#39;bil_1_5 mL";Actively Marketed\n';

var regex = /([\w ]+[^;\n]*|\"[^\"]*\")/g;

test = test.replace(regex, '\"\1\"'); // wrap in double quotes
test = test.replace(/\"\"/g, '\"'); // replace 2 quotes with one
```

Now you should have what you want.

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks! Though firstly I thought it was possible to combine expressions, with logical ( {1} and not {2}) 

where 
{1} = [^;]+
and {2} =  \"(([a-zA-Z&;#0-9_ ])+)\"